# How to update Argo CLI?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, fedora, argo-workflows, argoproj

I want to use Argo v2.4.0 and I ran the following command:

```
oc apply -n <my_ns> -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo/v2.4.0/manifests/install.yaml
```

This did not change the output of `argo version` (v2.3.0) notibly because it is installing Argo on the cluster and `argo version` points to my local binary. In order to update Argo cli, I ran the following command:

```
curl -sLO https://github.com/argoproj/argo/releases/download/v2.12.0-rc2/argo-linux-amd64.gz
gunzip argo-linux-amd64.gz
```

This gives me an error:
`gzip: argo-linux-amd64.gz: not in gzip format`

I want to update my Argo in order to parse a workflow.yaml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In general:**

Follow the download instructions for your target [Argo Workflows release](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/releases/tag/v3.1.3).

**Specific to 2.4.0:**

The download links were incorrect for 2.4.0.

The binaries have been replaced by gzipped binaries. You can use the download/gunzip process from your original post now.

**Original answer (OUTDATED):**

The [download instructions](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/releases/tag/v2.12.0-rc2) for that release are incorrect. Usually the binaries are compressed, but for some reason they aren't for 2.12.0-rc2.

Try again without the `.gz` extension.

```
$ curl -sLO https://github.com/argoproj/argo/releases/download/v2.12.0-rc2/argo-linux-amd64
$ chmod +x argo-linux-amd64
$ ./argo-linux-amd64
```

I'll try to get the release page fixed.

Comment: `./argo-linux-amd64: line 1: Not: command not found` after the last command.

Comment: @AviralSrivastava the non-gzipped binaries have been replaced with gzipped binaries. So you can use the commands from your original post now. Or is that what you're doing, and still getting the command-not-found error?

Answer (score -1):

I was getting similar errors. After trying the below commands, it worked for me.

```
# Download the binary
curl -sLO https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/releases/download/v0.0.0-dev-dataflow-37/argo-linux-amd64.gz

# Unzip
gunzip argo-linux-amd64.gz

# Make binary executable
chmod +x argo-linux-amd64

# Move binary to path
mv ./argo-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/argo
```

Hope it helps. Thanks!

Comment: DataFlow is a related project, and as far as I know that binary will work fine. But to be safe you should download the binary for the latest version of Argo Workflows: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/releases