# How to install Argo CLI?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argo-workflows

I am trying to install Argo CLI by following this (https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/releases) documentation.

```
# Download the binary
curl -sLO https://github.com/argoproj/argo/releases/download/v3.1.3/argo-linux-amd64.gz

# Unzip
gunzip argo-linux-amd64.gz

# Make binary executable
chmod +x argo-linux-amd64

# Move binary to path
mv ./argo-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/argo

# Test installation
argo version
```

The above instructions are not working. So, I followed the answer to this ([How to update Argo CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64916480/how-to-update-argo-cli)) question.

```
curl -sLO https://github.com/argoproj/argo/releases/download/v2.12.0-rc2/argo-linux-amd64
chmod +x argo-linux-amd64
./argo-linux-amd64
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
./argo-linux-amd64: line 1: Not: command not found
```

I also tried moving the `argo-linux-amd64` binary to `/usr/local/bin/argo` but still getting the same error (as expected).

Is there any solution to this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The download links on the Releases page are incorrect. Try this one:

```
curl -sLO https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/releases/download/v3.1.3/argo-linux-amd64.gz
```

I've submitted an [issue](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/issues/6440) to get the links fixed.